# Google Script execute external php

Tags: google-apps-script

How can I run a script from a google spreadsheets which execute execute a php file on an external server

I want to automate the inserts in the spreadsheets to my data base with the triggers.
Im missing the part to call to a php i´ve got

Answer (score 2):

Use [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch) document and make an URLFetch to your php external server.